# grep to find words with all vowels

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Using `grep -E` and regular expressions I need to find words containing all of a group of characters in no particular order. For instance a word containing all vowels (aeiou) however the vowels can appear in the word in any order.

Comment: Is that some kind of home work?

Comment: Yes,this was a past homework problem I couldn't figure out and would really like to understand how to do it.

Comment: Try: `grep -Ew "*[aeiou]*" file`

Comment: Even though this is/was a homework Q it's perfectly legit Q to ask here!

Answer (score 7):

This rule "contains all of `aeiou` in some order" can't be expressed in a POSIX Extended Regular Expression (`grep -E`) of reasonable size.

Here's a big one that lists all 120 permutations of aeiou as alternatives:

```
a.*e.*i.*o.*u|a.*e.*i.*u.*o|a.*e.*o.*i.*u|a.*e.*o.*u.*i|a.*e.*u.*i.*o|a.*e.*u.*o.*i|a.*i.*e.*o.*u|a.*i.*e.*u.*o|a.*i.*o.*e.*u|a.*i.*o.*u.*e|a.*i.*u.*e.*o|a.*i.*u.*o.*e|a.*o.*e.*i.*u|a.*o.*e.*u.*i|a.*o.*i.*e.*u|a.*o.*i.*u.*e|a.*o.*u.*e.*i|a.*o.*u.*i.*e|a.*u.*e.*i.*o|a.*u.*e.*o.*i|a.*u.*i.*e.*o|a.*u.*i.*o.*e|a.*u.*o.*e.*i|a.*u.*o.*i.*e|e.*a.*i.*o.*u|e.*a.*i.*u.*o|e.*a.*o.*i.*u|e.*a.*o.*u.*i|e.*a.*u.*i.*o|e.*a.*u.*o.*i|e.*i.*a.*o.*u|e.*i.*a.*u.*o|e.*i.*o.*a.*u|e.*i.*o.*u.*a|e.*i.*u.*a.*o|e.*i.*u.*o.*a|e.*o.*a.*i.*u|e.*o.*a.*u.*i|e.*o.*i.*a.*u|e.*o.*i.*u.*a|e.*o.*u.*a.*i|e.*o.*u.*i.*a|e.*u.*a.*i.*o|e.*u.*a.*o.*i|e.*u.*i.*a.*o|e.*u.*i.*o.*a|e.*u.*o.*a.*i|e.*u.*o.*i.*a|i.*a.*e.*o.*u|i.*a.*e.*u.*o|i.*a.*o.*e.*u|i.*a.*o.*u.*e|i.*a.*u.*e.*o|i.*a.*u.*o.*e|i.*e.*a.*o.*u|i.*e.*a.*u.*o|i.*e.*o.*a.*u|i.*e.*o.*u.*a|i.*e.*u.*a.*o|i.*e.*u.*o.*a|i.*o.*a.*e.*u|i.*o.*a.*u.*e|i.*o.*e.*a.*u|i.*o.*e.*u.*a|i.*o.*u.*a.*e|i.*o.*u.*e.*a|i.*u.*a.*e.*o|i.*u.*a.*o.*e|i.*u.*e.*a.*o|i.*u.*e.*o.*a|i.*u.*o.*a.*e|i.*u.*o.*e.*a|o.*a.*e.*i.*u|o.*a.*e.*u.*i|o.*a.*i.*e.*u|o.*a.*i.*u.*e|o.*a.*u.*e.*i|o.*a.*u.*i.*e|o.*e.*a.*i.*u|o.*e.*a.*u.*i|o.*e.*i.*a.*u|o.*e.*i.*u.*a|o.*e.*u.*a.*i|o.*e.*u.*i.*a|o.*i.*a.*e.*u|o.*i.*a.*u.*e|o.*i.*e.*a.*u|o.*i.*e.*u.*a|o.*i.*u.*a.*e|o.*i.*u.*e.*a|o.*u.*a.*e.*i|o.*u.*a.*i.*e|o.*u.*e.*a.*i|o.*u.*e.*i.*a|o.*u.*i.*a.*e|o.*u.*i.*e.*a|u.*a.*e.*i.*o|u.*a.*e.*o.*i|u.*a.*i.*e.*o|u.*a.*i.*o.*e|u.*a.*o.*e.*i|u.*a.*o.*i.*e|u.*e.*a.*i.*o|u.*e.*a.*o.*i|u.*e.*i.*a.*o|u.*e.*i.*o.*a|u.*e.*o.*a.*i|u.*e.*o.*i.*a|u.*i.*a.*e.*o|u.*i.*a.*o.*e|u.*i.*e.*a.*o|u.*i.*e.*o.*a|u.*i.*o.*a.*e|u.*i.*o.*e.*a|u.*o.*a.*e.*i|u.*o.*a.*i.*e|u.*o.*e.*a.*i|u.*o.*e.*i.*a|u.*o.*i.*a.*e|u.*o.*i.*e.*a
```

and here's one that's shorter, but harder to follow because of nesting:

```
a.*(e.*(i.*[ou]|o.*[iu]|u.*[io])|i.*(e.*[ou]|o.*[eu]|u.*[eo])|o.*(e.*[iu]|i.*[eu]|u.*[ei])|u.*(e.*[io]|i.*[eo]|o.*[ei]))|e.*(a.*(i.*[ou]|o.*[iu]|u.*[io])|i.*(a.*[ou]|o.*[au]|u.*[ao])|o.*(a.*[iu]|i.*[au]|u.*[ai])|u.*(a.*[io]|i.*[ao]|o.*[ai]))|i.*(a.*(e.*[ou]|o.*[eu]|u.*[eo])|e.*(a.*[ou]|o.*[au]|u.*[ao])|o.*(a.*[eu]|e.*[au]|u.*[ae])|u.*(a.*[eo]|e.*[ao]|o.*[ae]))|o.*(a.*(e.*[iu]|i.*[eu]|u.*[ei])|e.*(a.*[iu]|i.*[au]|u.*[ai])|i.*(a.*[eu]|e.*[au]|u.*[ae])|u.*(a.*[ei]|e.*[ai]|i.*[ae]))|u.*(a.*(e.*[io]|i.*[eo]|o.*[ei])|e.*(a.*[io]|i.*[ao]|o.*[ai])|i.*(a.*[eo]|e.*[ao]|o.*[ae])|o.*(a.*[ei]|e.*[ai]|i.*[ae]))
```

Both of those are assuming that the words you're searching for are in a file with one word per line. If not, you'll have to change all the `.`'s to `[^ ]` to match non-space characters. (Note: `\S` from perl is available in many regexp engines, possibly including the grep you use, but perl-compatible regular expressions are not a standard grep feature so `[^ ]` it must be.)

I wouldn't attempt to write either of those regexps by hand. I used a permutation generator for the first one, and did a lot of macro recording and replaying in vim to write the second one.

But let's see what happens if we invert the problem. Instead of trying to match a string containing all the vowels, try to match the opposite: a string that is **missing at least one of the vowels**.

(From here on out, I'm sticking with the assumption of one word per line in the input.)

A word that's missing the `a` matches `^[^a]*$` (from beginning to end, it's made of characters other than `a`).

A word that's missing the `e` matches `^[^e]*$`
A word that's missing the `i` matches `^[^i]*$`
A word that's missing the `o` matches `^[^o]*$`
A word that's missing the `u` matches `^[^u]*$`

A word that's missing `a` OR missing `e` OR missing `i` OR missing `o` OR missing `u` matches

```
^([^a]*|[^e]*|[^i]*|[^o]*|[^u]*)$
```

So this grep command gives you all the words you don't want:

```
grep -E '^([^a]*|[^e]*|[^i]*|[^o]*|[^u]*)$' wordlist
```

and the handy `-v` option gives you the words you *do* want:

```
grep -vE '^([^a]*|[^e]*|[^i]*|[^o]*|[^u]*)$' wordlist
```

Add `-i` if desired.

The inversion technique is something to keep in mind when writing regular expressions. Sometimes a really complicated regexp is the inverse of a simpler one.

Comment: awesome. I was thinking about `printf` ing `printf` all the way back from the daycare. the `-v` did *not* occur to me. one thing though - I think you might want like `[^ ]*` instead of `.*`. That was going to be my big revelation... *sigh*

Answer (score 3):

Does it need to be a *single* `grep` command? 
To find all words containing each vowel at least once (in any order),
the simplest command is

```
grep a word_list | grep e | grep i | grep o | grep u
```

Add `-i` if you need to be case-insensitive.

Comment: yes i need just a single grep command, sorry i forgot to specify that

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a trick question, IMO, since `grep` does not possess a true AND operator. You can use various tricks within `grep` to partially get a AND but it only works in certain situations.

For example you can use the wildcard operator to match strings where they have your pattern, but it'll only match it if it's in the exact same order as your pattern.

#### Sample file

```
$ cat words.txt 
aeiou
a1e2i3o4u5
dog
blh
spkz
uoiea
```

#### 1. Example using .*

```
$ grep -E ".*a.*e.*i.*o.*u.*" words.txt 
aeiou
a1e2i3o4u5
```

This matches only strings that have the sequence of `aeiou` in that same progression. But it fails to match `uoiea`.

#### 2. Example using [aeiou]

```
$ grep -E [aeiou] words.txt 
aeiou
a1e2i3o4u5
dog
uoiea
```

This approach matches, but it's too loose, matching anything that contains at least 1 of the letters in our pattern.

#### 3. Example using multiple greps

```
$ grep a words.txt | grep e | grep i | grep o | grep u
aeiou
a1e2i3o4u5
uoiea
```

If you're forced to use `grep`, this is really the only option you have available to you if your intent is to match all the characters in a set.

#### 4. Example using awk

```
$ awk '/a/ && /e/ && /i/ && /o/ && /u/ { print }' words.txt 
aeiou
a1e2i3o4u5
uoiea
```

As if often the case when dealing with Unix. If you're willing to switch to the appropriate tool, a seemingly impossible task becomes easy. Here by switching to `awk` we can now make use of an actual AND operator (`&&`) and now we can specify what set of characters we want to find.

#### 5. Example using `grep`'s other switches, (-w)

If the strings you're matching are all guaranteed to be single words you could make use of the `-w` switch.

```
   -w, --word-regexp
        Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. 
        The test is that the matching substring must  either  be  at  the
        beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded by a non-word constituent 
        character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or
        followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent 
        characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
```

So as long as the series of letters from the set `[aeiou]` is all contiguous you could leverage this switch like so:

```
$ grep -Ew "*[aeiou]*" words.txt 
aeiou
uoiea
```

But if you have to deal with multi-case phrases then it too will fail you:

```
$ echo "I love Fort Lauderdale" | grep -Ew "*[aeiou]*" 
$
```

However if we make use of the `-i` switch so that `grep`'s case insensitive, then it will once again work:

```
$ echo "I love Fort Lauderdale" | grep -Ewi "*[aeiou]*"
I love Fort Lauderdale
```

Comment: I think in that last bit you need `echo "I love Fort Lauderdale" | grep -Ewi "*[aeiou]*"` and it should work.

Comment: @Harvinder - thanks that fixed it. Updated A.