# Find characters in the file

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I need to find lines in the text file that have at least one `x` *and* at least two `y`s.

I tried the following:

```
grep -E "x.*y{2}" file.txt
```

This method did not work. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Does it need to be grep?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be grep.

Comment: And you need it to match any of `x blah y blah y` or `y blah x blah y` or `y blah y blah x`? I mean, can they be in any order? And why does it need to be done in a single grep call?

Comment: The ordering does not matter. I was looking for different variations, in particular with one regular expression.

Comment: Suspiciously similar to [grep to find words with all vowels](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156134/80216).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two consecutive grep calls:

```
grep 'x' file.txt | grep 'y.*y'
```

or one with the three possibilities:

```
grep -E 'x.*y.*y|y.*x.*y|y.*y.*x' file.txt
```

Comment: It has to be one regular expression.

Comment: @Elijah I modified my answer. Please be more specific in future questions.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I did not specify the pattern I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If they can be found in any order, I doubt you can get anything shorter than @jofel's answer. If you can use other tools, here are some options:

1. perl

   ```
   perl -pe ' /x/ && /y.*y/ || next' file
   ```
2. awk

   ```
   awk '/x/ && /y.*y/' file
   ```

Anything else I can think of would have to use the three-pronged approach of @jofel.